# Options of an arc in Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, user-interface, canvas, tkinter, automatic-ref-counting

What are the 4 initial numbers of `.create_arc()`?

As in:

```
myArc = myCanvas.create_arc(p1, p2, p3, p4, start=p5, extent=p6)
```

'p' being 'parameter'.

I don't get what `p1`-`p4` do.

How can I create an arc and position it on the bottom left corner of my canvas with the radius of the canvas' width/height?

I need to know this because I have to program a GUI for Monte Carlo simulation to approximate Pi.

Comment: [Check here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_arc-method), those are the bbox of the entire arc.

Comment: The calling sequence is actually `create_arc(x0, y0, x1, y1, option, ...)`.See [_Canvas arc objects_](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_arc.html) — it's a slice, or wedge, taken out of an oval which is mathematically an ellipse, so also look at [_Canvas oval objects_](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_oval.html). The two options you're using are the starting and extent of the angle in degrees.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates represent the opposite corners of a rectangle that will encloses the oval that defines the arc. In other words, the arc will only appear within the area bounded by that rectangle.

From the official tcl/tk documentation (the technology that tkinter is built upon) (see http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M111):

> Items of type arc appear on the display as arc-shaped regions. An arc
>   is a section of an oval delimited by two angles (specified by the
>   -start and -extent options) and displayed in one of several ways 
>   (specified by the -style option).
>
> Arcs are created with widget commands of the following form:

```
pathName create arc x1 y1 x2 y2 ?option value option value ...?
pathName create arc coordList ?option value option value ...?
```

> The arguments x1, y1, x2, and y2 or coordList give the coordinates of
>   two diagonally opposite corners of a rectangular region enclosing the
>   oval that defines the arc. After the coordinates there may be any
>   number of option-value pairs, each of which sets one of the
>   configuration options for the item. These same option-value pairs may
>   be used in itemconfigure widget commands to change the item's
>   configuration. An arc item becomes the current item when the mouse
>   pointer is over any part that is painted or (when fully transparent)
>   that would be painted if both the -fill and -outline options were
>   non-empty.

Comment: Meaning in a canvas with height/width 1000 I need 0, 1000, 1000, 0 to make the entire canvas available for drawing my arc?

Comment: @steveroch_rs: only if you want your arc to be as tall and wide as the entire canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

Like this :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *
from random import randint
root = Tk()
can = Canvas(root,width=400.5,height=400,bg="#CCCCCC",highlightbackground="#006699")
can.place(x=10,y=10)

"""
Sec = SECTOR
--------------------
|Sec-1       Sec-2 | 
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|Sec-4       Sec-3 |
--------------------
"""
deviation = 2 #NEED SHOW ALL ARCs IN CANVAS(FULL)
size = 5  #MEAN WIDTH(BORDER THICKNES)
def setARC(radius,sector,deviation,size):
    w,h = can.config("width")[-1],can.config("height")[-1]
    startAngle = 0
    position = list()
    if sector == 1 :
        positions = 0+deviation,radius+size+deviation,radius+size+deviation,0+deviation
        startAngle = 90
    elif sector == 2 :
        positions = int(w)-radius-size-deviation,deviation,int(w)-deviation,radius+deviation+size
    elif sector == 3:
        positions = int(w)-radius-size-deviation,int(h)-deviation,int(w)-deviation,int(h)-radius-deviation-size
        startAngle = 270
    elif sector == 4:
        positions = deviation,int(h)-radius-deviation-size,radius+deviation+size,int(h)-deviation
        startAngle = 180
    can.create_arc(positions,start=startAngle,extent=90,outline="black",width=size,style=ARC,tags="Sector-"+str(sector))
    sizer.set(radius)

def change(e):
    w,h = int(can.config("width")[-1]),int(can.config("height")[-1])
    radius = sizer.get()
    for x in can.find_all():
        wrd = can.gettags(x)[0]
        if wrd.startswith("Sector-") :
            position = list()
            if wrd[-1] == "1":
                position = [0+deviation,radius+size+deviation,radius+size+deviation,0+deviation]
            elif wrd[-1] == "2":
                position = [w-radius-size-deviation,deviation,w-deviation,radius+deviation+size]
            elif wrd[-1] == "3":
                position = [w-radius-size-deviation,h-deviation,w-deviation,h-radius-deviation-size]
            elif wrd[-1] == "4":
                position = [deviation,h-radius-deviation-size,radius+deviation+size,h-deviation]
            can.coords(x, tuple(position))
            Rcolor = (min(w,h)*255)/(radius if radius > 0 else 1)
            outColor = "#%02X%02X%02X"%tuple(randint(0,255) for i in range(3))
            can.itemconfig(x,outline=outColor)


sizer = Scale(root, from_=0, to=min(can.config("width")[-1],can.config("height")[-1]), orient=VERTICAL,command=change)
sizer.place(x=10+int(can.place_info()["x"])+int(can.config("width")[-1]),y=int(can.place_info()["y"]),\
            height=min(int(can.config("width")[-1]),int(can.config("height")[-1])))

sizer.set(200)

for i in range(1,5,1):
    setARC(200,i,2,5)


root.geometry("800x450+50+50")
root.config(bg="#006699")
root.mainloop()
```

The point of consideration is to determine the aspect size of the items.

`w,h = int(can.config("width")[-1]),int(can.config("height")[-1])`

You must also add tags to the canvas element.

`can.create_arc(positions,start=startAngle,extent=90,outline="black",width=size,style=ARC,tags="Sector-"+str(sector))`